# Little confused about Semaphore Class

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

I have kind of confused about the "Semaphore" class in java.util.concurrent package. Here are my code snippet:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class TestSemaphore {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Semaphore limit = new Semaphore(2);
        SemaphoreAA s = new SemaphoreAA(limit);
        AAThread a = new AAThread(s);
        Thread[] sThread = new Thread[100];
        for(int i = 0; i<100; i++){
            sThread[i] = new Thread(a,"[sThread"+i+"]");
            sThread[i].start();

        }
    }
}

class SemaphoreAA{
    private static int counter;
    private Semaphore limit;

    public SemaphoreAA(Semaphore limit){
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public void increment() throws InterruptedException{
        System.out.printf("%-15s%-25s%5d%n",Thread.currentThread().getName()," : Before Increment. Current counter: ",counter);
        limit.acquire();
        System.out.printf("%-15s%-25s%n",Thread.currentThread().getName()," : Get the resource. Start to increment.");
        counter++;
        System.out.printf("%-20s%-40s%5d%n",Thread.currentThread().getName()," : Increment is done. Current counter: ",counter );
        limit.release();
    }
}

class AAThread implements Runnable{
    private SemaphoreAA s;

    public AAThread(SemaphoreAA s){
        this.s = s;

    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            s.increment();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I understand it can be used to control accesses to resources. And if I set the limit to one, like this "Semaphore limit = new Semaphore(1);", it seems like a lock. It was proved. If I set the limit to two, I expect there are two threads in the given time to access to the increment() method and it might cause data race. The output might be like this:

> - [sThread3] : Before Increment. Current counter:     2
> - [sThread4] : Before Increment. Current counter:     2
> - [sThread3] : Get the resource. Start to increment.
> - [sThread4] : Get the resource. Start to increment.
> - [sThread3] : Increment is done. Current counter:      3
> - [sThread4] : Increment is done. Current counter:      3

However, though I had tried several times, the result expected didn't occur. So I wanna know if I misunderstood it. Thanks.

Comment: You should put the loop in the run() method - starting a thread takes time and reduces the likelihood of interleaving...

Comment: It is in a thread @assylias

Comment: @RamonBoza Each thread only runs one instruction `s.increment()` so the time to start the thread is actually much longer than what `increment` does - to have a chance to observe interleaving and racing, you need to make the calls to `increment` closer in time. For example by calling `increment` 10000 times in each thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You understood it right.**

> However, though I had tried several times, the result expected didn't occur.

Just because it can appear doesn't mean it will. This is the problem with most concurrency bugs: they sometimes appear, sometimes not.

If you want to increase the likelihood of an error you can increase the number of `Thread`s or create/start them in two different loops after each other.

Comment: I got you and that's why I had tried several times and increase the number of threads to 100 (not 10) to capture the expected result. However, it didn't work.

Comment: @franksunn Try assigning the value to a local variable before incrementing then do `if(local + 1 != counter) { fail(); } `  In that case you can run it over and over and over again until it eventually fails.

Comment: Also remove the `System.out.println` as it adds additional synchronization points in which may effect your outcome